# How to handle json with different type but same key in jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I request a rest service where the json result holds a list of place objects o just one place object but both with the same key:

```
{
    place:[{lat:12, lon:12}, {lat:12, lon:12}]
}
```

or

```
{
    place: {lat: 12, lon:12}
}
```

Is there a way to handle this with the jackson json parser to I've got always a list of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Have you tried it? For first example, it would seem like your object model would be something like:

```
public class Places {
  public List<Place> place:
```

}

public class Place {
     public int lat, lon;
   }

and you would get expected JSON.